# How to detect request came from either web or api route files?

Tags: php, laravel

I have two similar routes inside both `routes/api.php` and `routes/web.php` files:

```
// routes/api.php
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('running-server-processes', 'ServerProcessesController@running_list');

// routes/web.php
Route::middleware('auth')->get('running-server-processes', 'ServerProcessesController@running_list');
```

Also here is the called method:

```
public function running_list(Request $request){
    dd(request()->wantsJson());
    //=> false
}
```

The output is always `false`. I mean in both cases, when I call it by a browser (web) and when I call it through the postman (API). Why? How can I separate them?

Comment: When you send your request via postman, do you set the `accept` header to say you expect `json`?

Comment: No, I have to do that? Or `auth:api` does that thing? @Unflux

Comment: You should have different endpoints for API calls anyway...